# C# alternative for mongo find({ _id: {$in : list}})

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, c#-4.0, mongodb-query

C# alternative for mongo `find({ _id: {$in : list}})`

I need all the document having _id values in list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```cs
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.In("_id", list);
var result = yourCollection.Find(filter).ToList()
```